# Nginx location rules not applying

Tags: nginx, server, location

I want to run both WordPress and YOURLS on one domain which is configured by a NGINX server block (not the default site). Since both need to handle URLs differently, they need different `try_files` directives. WordPress sits on the root of the domain (domain.tld), while YOURLS is being installed to the /g/ directory. Despite the two location rules, I get 404s on any links generated by YOURLS (e.g. domain.tld/g/linkname, all are redirects to external URLs), though I can access the admin backend.
As far as I read, declaring to location rules (one for /g/, and one for /) should suffice in order to let NGINX handle the direct and the /g/ URLS differently - is there something in wrong in my thinking? 
The `try_files` rules are correct and do work well on other single-application server block (WordPress as well as YOURLS on installs on separate server blocks).

The server block definition config looks like this:

```html
server {
 listen [::]:80;
 listen 80;

 server_name domain.tld www.domain.tld;

 return 301 https://domain.tld$request_uri;

}

server {
 listen [::]:443 ssl;
 listen 443 ssl;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.tld/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.tld/privkey.pem;
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains";


 root /var/www/html/domain.tld;

 # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
 index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html index.php;

 server_name domain.tld www.domain.tld;

 location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_intercept_errors off;
 }

 location /g/ {
     try_files $uri $uri/ /yourls-loader.php$is_args$args;
        expires 14d;
        add_header Cache-Control 'public';
 }

 location / {
  try_files  $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
 }

 # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
 # concurs with nginx's one
 #
 location ~ /\.ht {
  deny all;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with the location /g/ `try_files` directive is that the path to the YOURLS loader isn't correct.  If the URL handler (yourls-loader.php) lies within the /g directory, the path to it has to be changed to include the `/g` directory:

`try_files $uri $uri/ /g/yourls-loader.php$is_args$args;`

The location rule does not imply that each path is handled from that location as well, but rather from the root path given above.